# How Can I convert this complex a string into JSON with "" in key values?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, javascript-objects

I am trying to convert a string to json.

```
var str = "[{Value:0.64,Rate:Hourly,Description:Hourly if more than 50 hours,Upper Limit:null},{Value:1.68,Rate:Hourly,Description:Hourly if less than 400 hours,Upper Limit:500}]"
```

I tried with stringify and parse but that didn't work.

I tried with below function :

```
function getJsonData(query){
    let arrayOfKeyValues = query.split(',');
    let modifiedArray =  new Array();
    console.log(arrayOfKeyValues);
    for(let i=0;i< arrayOfKeyValues.length;i++){
        let arrayValues = arrayOfKeyValues[i].split(':');
        let arrayString ='"'+arrayValues[0]+'"'+':'+'"'+arrayValues[1]+'"';
        modifiedArray.push(arrayString);
    }
    let jsonDataString = '{'+modifiedArray.toString()+'}';
    let jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonDataString);
    console.log(jsonData);
    console.log(typeof jsonData);
    return jsonData;
}
```

Is there a way to use regex or this function to get the expected output with double quotes ("") added
to each key value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to as least make the assumption that your KEYS all do not contain a comma.
Because, say you have:
{a:b,c,d:e}
It is ambiguous whether it should be: {a:"b","c,d":"e"} or {a:"b,c",d:"e"}

Just for simplicity, I am also assuming there is no {, }, : characters in your key or value...

The expression is:

```js
JSON.parse(
  str
  .replace(new RegExp('{','g'),'{"')
  .replace(new RegExp('}','g'),'"}')
  .replace(new RegExp(':','g'),'":"')
  .replace(new RegExp(',([^{][^,]*:)','g'),'","$1')
)
```

This will be the outcome:

[image]

Comment: It should be {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key3":"value3","key4":"value4"}.
Your code works but only issue is on key it doesn;t add double quote.

Comment: no...I added double quote to keys. Just the JSON.parse will automatically remove all unnecessary double quote in keys (in fact a browser console display standard)

Comment: okay will try once. I was debugging in browser. I will Check and accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this code in my template but it doesn't work.  (I tried adding toString and the replace too)
value[i].toString.replace is not a functio..

Comment: @shuklayogesh can you give the example string so that I can do some debugging?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "[{Value:0.64,Rate:Hourly,Description:Hourly if more than 50 hours,Upper Limit:null},{Value:1.68,Rate:Hourly,Description:Hourly if less than 400 hours,Upper Limit:500}]"

const regStr = str
.replace(/:/g,'":"')
.replace(/,/g,'","')
.replace(/}","{/g,'"},{"')
.replace(/^\[{/,'[{"')
.replace(/}]$/, '"}]')


jsonResult = JSON.parse(regStr)
console.log(jsonResult);
```